# Wordpress - get parameter from apply_filters()

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm totally new to wordpress, so apologies for the poor explanation.
I have this code:

```
$text = apply_filters( 'prefix_xml_feeds_productname_variant', $text, $product_item->ID, $vars->ID );
```

and need to display `$vars->ID` in my function:

```
function custom_product_name() {
    global $product;
    
    $product_name = $product->get_name();
    $sku = $product->get_sku();
    
    $text = 'Example.com ' . $sku . ' ' . $product_name . ' ' . $vars->ID;         
    return $text; 
}
add_filter( 'prefix_xml_feeds_productname_variant', 'custom_product_name' );
```

How can I access `$vars` variable value? Is anyone able to help me?

Comment: **Please do not ask the same question twice** - Duplicate: [Get data from apply_filters('prefix_xml_feeds_productname_variant') function in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63967018/get-data-from-apply-filtersprefix-xml-feeds-productname-variant-function-in).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get data from apply\_filters('prefix\_xml\_feeds\_productname\_variant') function in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63967018/get-data-from-apply-filtersprefix-xml-feeds-productname-variant-function-in)